# Sum of subset always returning 1

Tags: c++

Why this code is always returning 1 as result? I am finding out the sum of subset. This code always returns true.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool sum1(int arr[],int sum,int k,int tsum,int m,int n)
{   

    if(sum+arr[k]==m)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(sum+arr[k]+arr[k+1]<=m)
    {
        sum1(arr,sum+arr[k],k+1,tsum-arr[k],m,n);
    }
    if((sum+tsum-arr[k]>=m) && (sum+arr[k+1]<=m))
    {
        sum1(arr,sum,k+1,tsum-arr[k],m,n);
    }

    else if(k>n)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //return false;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={7,11,13,24};
    if(sum1(arr,0,1,55,1,4))
    {
        cout<<1;
    }
    else{
        cout<<0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Compile with **all warnings enabled**, and use a debugger. Read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: there is no warning !!

Comment: Then you aren't compiling **with warnings enabled**.

Comment: Off the top, you never use the return values of those recursive `sum1` calls. They also don't have any side effects; so these calls are elaborate no-ops.

Comment: can you say me why its always returning 1?? menas its always finding a Sum of Subset

Comment: If there is no warning, get a better compiler! There is at least one code path which returns from the function without a `return` statement. If this path is taken the behavior is undefined.

Comment: What if none case is satisfied? Remove that commented return false

Comment: i removed that commented statement no everytime its showing zero

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra it won't replace 11 by 1 and see

Comment: @VidorVistrom replaced still its zero

Comment: did u check ? @VidorVistrom

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra https://ideone.com/TfqNlW and https://ideone.com/VX6TWz

Comment: @VidorVistrom check with 31 its still showing zero when we can get 31 by adding up 7 + 11 + 13

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra could you explain your variables?

Comment: @VidorVistrom sum is intialised to zero and then it adds up with the element and checks m is present or not k is the index of the element tsum is the total sum of the elemnt m is the sum tht is to be found and n is the range

Comment: @VidorVistrom yes

Comment: @VidorVistrom did u get ?

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra Check the answer.

Comment: @VidorVistrom thnx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight error you made while passing the values inside the function.

You must begin by element k=0 as you have to search by 0th index first, not 1.

**Beware** that this will allow you to search for sum starting from **0th index till the end**. That is, in this particular case, `7` or `7+11` or `7+11+13` or `7+11+13+24`. With the code the OP provides you cannot check something **like**  `11+24`.

Here:

- sum is current sum of the elements traversed yet.
- k is the index to begin with
- tsum is total sum of the array elements
- m is the sum of sub array elements to be found
- n is the size of the array(or the range you want to check from the kth index).

OP also forgot to add return statements before the recursive calls. Also the k>n should be checked early.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool sum1(int arr[],int sum,int k,int tsum,int m,int n)
{

    if(sum+arr[k]==m)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(k>n)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(sum+arr[k]+arr[k+1]<=m)
    {
        return sum1(arr,sum+arr[k],k+1,tsum-arr[k],m,n-1);
    }
    else if((sum+tsum-arr[k]>=tsum) && (sum+arr[k+1]<=tsum))
    {
        return sum1(arr,sum,k+1,tsum-arr[k],m,n);
    }


    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]={7,11,13,24};
    if(sum1(arr,0,0,55,31,4))
    {
        cout<<1;
    }
    else{
        cout<<0;
    }
}
```

You can also manually specify the range to check. Example k=1 and n=4 will add these possibilities:  `11+13` or `11+13+24`. But beware, if you change n, also change tsum correspondingly for the range. Example for k=0 and n=3 tsum should be 31.

Comment: can you help me in printing those elements which adds up to that m ?? i am using a vector and its giving robust answers

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra Yeah simply add it to the vector before recursive calls and at the end condition in recursion. See this: https://ideone.com/p3i1JK. Just in case to avoid some leaks, clear the vector right before return false in both the instances.

Comment: this program fails when repetition of elements is there

Comment: @BiswajitMohapatra it works. https://ideone.com/PIb20o... show me a case where it doesn't I might be able to sort